# ASP.NET No suitable constructor for WebSocketManagerMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, dnx50

I got error when created WebSocketManagerExtensions like this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
A suitable constructor for type 
'CustomerManagementCore.WebSocketManager.WebSocketManagerMiddleware' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
```

`MapWebSocketManager` method:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder MapWebSocketManager(this IApplicationBuilder app,
                                                            PathString path,
                                                            WebSocketHandler handler)
{
    return app.Map(path, (_app) => _app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketManagerMiddleware>(handler));
}
```

`WebSocketManagerMiddleware` constructor:

```
public WebSocketManagerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
                                      WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler)
{
    _next = next;
    _webSocketHandler = webSocketHandler;
}
```

I know if there is something error with my `WebSocketManagerMiddleware` constructor, but I have no idea.
Anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a silly question but did you add WebSocketHandler to the IServiceCollection in `ConfigureServices` in your startup class?

Comment: Oh my bad! I forgot about that. It's been solved now, thank you.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer then if you wouldn't mind accepting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error I would guess `WebSocketHandler` was not added to the `IServicesCollection` in your startup class. Once you add it to the services collection, it should be able to be injected as expected. Typically this is done in the `ConfigureServices` method for an ASP.NET Core application created from the default templates.

Comment: Thanks! In my case the I solved by adding this line `services.AddTransient<ChatWebSocketHandler>();`